# A simple counter example for Open Mapping Theorem when Linearity Assumption is Dropped

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

I was studying on Follan's Real Analysis book and in Chapter 5.3, I saw the Open Mapping Theorem which stated (with some adjustment) as follows:

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ be linear and bounded operator. If $T$ is surjective, then $T$ maps open sets to open set.

Then, based on the expression above, I expect if $T$ is nonlinear then the conclusion must fail. So I consider an example as follows: Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ be (simplest?) Banach spaces and then take a mapping $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x^2$. Then consider open interval $U:=(-1,1)$ then $f(U) = [0,1)$ which is not open. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I don't "do" functional analysis, but that is the standard good example in topology. (Though not surjective.)

Comment: But $f$ isn't surjective, so you don't have a counterexample.  Consider instead a cubic polynomial.

Comment: @Randall, Thanks for the comments. How about I change my $Y$ to $Y:=f(\mathbb{R})$ or simply taking $Y=[0,1]$ then I do have surjectivity right?

Comment: I think I might be shocked to learn that $[0,1]$ is a Banach space, but then again, I don't know anything about them.

Comment: Anyway, does $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^3 -3x^2$ work for the same reason as your proposed example?  It's bounded (in the operator sense), onto, but look at $f(0,3)$.

Comment: @Randall. There was a crank on this site who, among other odd  things, said  "Would you be shocked when I tell you that $1$ is a prime number?"

Comment: I just got my mind totally wrong, of course $[0,1]$ is not Bananch space, although it is complete, it does not preserve the algebraic requirment for being a vector space.... The example $x^3-3x^2$ works for me. Really nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^3 -3x^2$.  This is bounded (as it's continuous) and surjective.  However, the open set $(0,3)$ in the domain maps to $[-4,0)$, which isn't open.

(Aweygan gets the assist.)

Comment: Now I don’t like this answer because my intuition on what bounded means is totally shot without having linearity to rely on.  Is there a right notion of bounded nonlinear operator?